# cwac-wakeful collides with wakelocks

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have a quite strange issue with a cwac-wakeful library and wakelocks.

In my app, I'm using cwac-wakeful to periodically download a data from a web server and this works very well. But when somewhere in the app I acquire a wakelock (even when the set alarms were cancelled), cwac-wakeful starts to behave a little odd - it starts a job at full hours exactly every 5 minutes (14:00, 14:05...), regardless of set repeating interval.

Releasing the wakelock gives no effect and the only method to fix this is to completely restart the application.

I know that cwac-wakeful takes advantage of wakelocks while performing a job, so maybe the problem is here.

Here is a class that implements the **AlarmListener**.

```
public class ServiceWaker implements WakefulIntentService.AlarmListener
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServiceWaker.class);

    public ServiceWaker()
    {
        log.info("New ServiceWaker");
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager alarmManager, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Context context)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        long syncFrequency = Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("sync_frequency", "1"));
        syncFrequency = syncFrequency * 60 * 1000;

        log.info("Alarm scheduled with a repeat interval:" + syncFrequency);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000, syncFrequency, pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendWakefulWork(Context context)
    {
        log.info("Sent wakeful work");
        WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, CheckServiceWakeful.class);
    }

    @Override
    public long getMaxAge()
    {
        return AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES*2;
    }
}
```

Details:

- **Target SDK**: 17
- **Minimum SDK**: 12
- **Compile SDK**: 17
- **BuildTools version**: 19.0.3

Comment: "cwac-wakeful starts to behave a little odd - it starts a job at full hours exactly every 5 minutes (14:00, 14:05...), regardless of set repeating interval" -- `cwac-wakeful` doesn't *start* anything. Something is triggering your `WakefulIntentService`. Check your `AlarmManager` events via **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`**.

Comment: Thanks for this useful command, I have poked around the alarms and found out that this "odd behavior" is not caused by wakelocks. It is probably because I mistakenly call _scheduleAlarms_ several times, but it is curious that after a few calls, it always schedules with a repeat interval of 5 minutes. Unfortunately _cancelAlarms_ is not enough to get rid of this "false alarm" and application restart still remains the only solution.

`type=2 when=+3m9s642ms repeatInterval=60000 count=1`

Comment: I see that this issue is not particularly connected with a cwac-wakeful but with AlarmManager, though. It seems that canceling and setting the alarm at a fast pace is not vital for the system. After a few cycles of "set/cancel", the alarm gets uncontrollable - there is no way to cancel it and it always schedules at full hours, as I wrote before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer but I forgot to post it after I found out the solution.

The problem was an energy manager in my mobile. I have 3 battery plans available:

- Energy saving - runs only essential services
- Smart - prolongs the battery life by doing some optimization with wake locks, I have had this plan set to active
- Normal - everything runs normally

"Smart" plan was responsible for this issue. As I have read somewhere, when set to active, the system tries to batch wake locks and network tasks, so the mobile is not continuously being waken. Thus my task was being re-scheduled with a longer period, in order to run it with another tasks every - for example - 15 minutes.